# Exponentially Slimy Programming: Stacking Minecraft Slimes

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, recursion

[Slimes](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Slime) are cube shaped [enemies](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mob#Hostile_mobs) in [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) that break into multiple smaller versions of themselves when killed. For the purposes of this challenge we'll depict them as an 8×8 pixel image with 3 colors:

[image: 64x64 slime]

[image: 8x8 slime] ← True 8×8 version.

The precise RGB colors are:

- `0, 0, 0` for the eyes and mouth
- `110, 170, 90` for the central, darker green
- `116, 196, 96` for the outer, lighter green

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N and outputs an image of N sizes of slimes packed into a rectangle. Going from left to right, the image should follow the pattern of having:

- A stack of 2<sup>(N-1)</sup> 8×8 slimes.
- A stack of 2<sup>(N-2)</sup> 16×16 slimes.
- A stack of 2<sup>(N-3)</sup> 32×32 slimes.
- And so on until the stack only contains one slime.

The slime images larger than the 8×8 version ([image: 8x8 slime]) are generated by [nearest-neighbor upsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms) (i.e. just doubling all the pixels). Note that you must use the exact slime design and colors given here.

The final image will contain 2<sup>N</sup>-1 slimes and be 2<sup>(N+3)</sup>-8 pixels wide and 2<sup>(N+2)</sup> pixels tall.

The image may be output in any common image file format, saved to a file or printed/returned as a raw data stream, or directly displayed during runtime.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

## Examples

Your program should produce these exact results.

N = 1:

[image: N = 1]

N = 2:

[image: N = 2]

N = 3:

[image: N = 3]

N = 4:

[image: N = 4]

N = 5:

[image: N = 5]

N = 6:

[image: N = 6]

Larger N should work just as well.

Comment: I would upvote but I have no votes left. I'm leaving this comment so I'll remember to upvote tomorrow.

Comment: I'm upvoting your comment because I've run out of upvotes too.

Comment: "The slime images larger than the 8×8 version (￼) are generated by nearest-neighbor upsampling (i.e. just doubling all the pixels)." Did you mean quadruple all the pixels, make each pixel into a 2x2 square?

Comment: @Caridorc Doubling in each direction?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes, each pixel becomes 4, correct?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ok, I get it now, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 21):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
:"')^.,9&Xze`}+.E=p'F3ZaQ8e@qWt3$Y"G@-W1X"]&h[OOO;11 17E]5*29 7U24hhE&vEYG
```

The code works in [this commit](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/commit/c982fad0c28392938612b1a824b1dbc95aecac53), which is earlier than the challenge.

You can try it in [**MATL online**](https://matl.io/?code=%3A%22%27%29%5E.%2C9%26Xze%60%7D%2B.E%3Dp%27F3ZaQ8e%40qWt3%24Y%22G%40-W1X%22%5D%26h%5BOOO%3B11+17E%5D5%2a29+7U24hhE%26vEYG&inputs=5&version=19.0.0). This interpreter is still experimental. If it doesn't work, try refreshing the page and pressing "Run" again.

Here's an example run in the offline interpreter:

[image]

#### Explanation

```
:                     % Input N implicitly. Generate range [1 2 ... N]
"                     % For each k in [1 2 ... N]
  ')^.,9&Xze`}+.E=p'  %   Compressed string
  F3Za                %   Decompress with target alphabet [0 1 2]
  Q                   %   Add 1
  8e                  %   Reshape into 8×8 array containing values 1, 2, 3
  @qW                 %   Push 2 raised to k-1
  t                   %   Duplicate
  3$Y"                %   Repelem: interpolate image by factor 2 raised to k-1
  G@-W                %   Push 2 raised to N-k
  1X"                 %   Repmat: repeat the array vertically. Gives a vertical strip
                      %   of repeated subimages
]                     % End for each
&h                    % Concatenate all vertical strips horizontally. This gives a big
                      % 2D array containing 1, 2, 3, which represent the three colors
[OOO;11 17E]5*        % Push array [0 0 0; 11 17 9] and multiply by 5
29 7U24hhE            % Push array [29 49 24] and multiply by 2
&vE                   % Concatenate the two arrays vertically and multiply by 2.
                      % This gives the colormap [0 0 0; 110 170 90; 116 196 96]
YG                    % Take the array and the colormap and display as an image
```

Comment: "Larger N should work just as well.", but yours seems to give Out Of Memory/index errors already at n = 9. Is this only the online interpreter, or does this happen in the offline version as well?

Comment: @DavidMulder I have tested offline (compiler running on Matlab R2015b, Windows 7 64 bits, 4 GB RAM) for input up to `11` and it works. For `11` the result is an 8192×16376 image. For `12` it would be 16384×32760 (536 megapixels), requiring over 4 GB of RAM, which is more than my laptop can handle.

Comment: I like how the code starts with a smiley that is holding back his tears because of the intense emotions this code makes him feel :"')

Answer (score 15):

## Dyalog APL, <s>118</s> 113 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

`('P3',⌽∘⍴,255,∊)(3↑(116 196 96)(110 170 90))[⊃,/i{⊃⍪/⍵⍴⊂⍺⌿⍺/8 8⍴∊22923813097005 926134669613412⊤¨⍨⊂32⍴3}¨⌽i←2*⍳⎕]`

assuming `⎕IO=0`

From right to left:

`i←2*⍳⎕`  powers 1 2 4 ... 2<sup>n-1</sup>

`i{ }¨⌽i` iterate over powers (with `⍺`) and reversed powers (`⍵`)

`⊤¨⍨⊂32⍴3` decode each of the numbers on the left as 32 ternary digits

`8 8⍴∊` flatten and reshape to 8×8

`⍺⌿⍺/` replicate each row and column `⍺` times

`⍵⍴⊂` take `⍵` copies

`⊃⍪/` and stack them vertically

`⊃,/` join all results horizontally

`3↑(116 196 96)(110 170 90)` colours; `3↑` extends them with `(0 0 0)`

`[ ]` index the colours with each element of the matrix; result is a matrix of RGBs

`('P3',⌽∘⍴,255,∊)` is a "train" - a function that returns `'P3'` followed by the reversed shape of the argument, `255`, and the argument flattened.

Comment: I think you can write your program assuming `⎕IO←0` and just state it as a condition, outside of byte count. Many APL systems use that as a default. (Including yours LOL)

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES7), 326 <s>327</s> bytes

```
n=>{x=(d=document).body.appendChild(c=d.createElement`canvas`).getContext`2d`;c.width=2*(c.height=4*(p=2**n)));for(i=0;i<n;i++){c=-1;for(j of[...'0001000001111110022112200221122011111110011121110111111000010000'])for(x.fillStyle=['#74c460','#6eaa5a','#000'][j],c++,k=0;k<p;)x.fillRect(c%8*(_=2**i)+_*8,~~(c/8)*_+_*8*k++,_,_)}}
```

**Ungolfed ES6 Version**

[Try it yourself.](https://jsfiddle.net/st2esfyL/)

```
(n=>{
    x=(d=document).body.appendChild(c=d.createElement`canvas`).getContext`2d`;
    c.width=2*(c.height=4*(p=Math.pow(2,n)));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        c=-1;
        for(j of[...'0001000001111110022112200221122011111110011121110111111000010000'])
            for(x.fillStyle=['#74c460','#6eaa5a','#000'][j],c++,k=0;k<p;)
                x.fillRect(c%8*(_=Math.pow(2,i))+_*8,~~(c/8)*_+_*8*k++,_,_)
    }
})(4);
```

The only difference between the ES7 and ES6 version is using `**` instead of `Math.pow()`. You can also see, how you can invoke the function – in this example with `n=4`.

**Result**

[image]

---

**Edits**

- saved *1 byte* - found an unnecessary trailing semicolon `;`

---

<sup>This is pretty slow and might take some time for numbers greater 10.</sup>

Comment: the colours seem slightly off in the image here. Did you perhaps screenshot with f.lux on?

Comment: @Jezzamon Thanks for pointing it out – I did notice that, too. There's a *slight possibility* that I *might* have chosen "*Convert document's colors to the working space*" while importing the screenshot into Photoshop. The image is fixed now.

Comment: @Giles - Appreciate your comment, and in SO, that'd be totally appropriate, but here, we don't change others' programs - we tell them in comments.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 220 bytes

```
x,y,r;f(n){
printf("P3 %d %d 255 ",(8<<n)-8,4<<n);
for(y=0;y<4<<n;++y)for(r=0;r<n;++r)for(x=0;x<8<<r;++x)
puts("110 170 90\0 116 196 96\0 0 0 0"+12*
(117-"` t5L\rL\ru5tst5` "[x>>r+2|(y>>r)%8*2]>>(x>>r)%4*2&3));}
```

I added useless newlines for readability, score is without these newlines.

Defines a function `f(n)` that outputs a plain PPM image on stdout.

Comment: For some reason C answers are pretty elegant in my mind.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>267</s> <s>255</s> <s>254</s> <s>225</s> 212 bytes

```
G=10{11,17,9};Image@Join[##,2]&@@Table[Join@@Table[ImageData@ImageResize[Image[{t={g=G+{6,26,6},g,g,G,g,g,g,g},f={g,a=##&[G,G,G],a,g},e={g,b=0g,b,G,G,b,b,g},e,{a,a,G,g},{g,a,b,a},f,t}/255],4*2^j],2^(#-j)],{j,#}]&
```

*Saved <s>29</s> 42 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

Golfing suggestions welcome, especially for constructing the 8 by 8 (by 3) array `s`. Unfortunately, there is no "`ArrayResize`" analogue for `ImageResize`, so the array needs to be converted to an image (`Image`) before resizing, and then back to an array (`ImageData`) to do the `Join`ing.

Ungolfed:

```
(* dark green, light green, black *)
G = 10 {11, 17, 9};
g = G + {6, 26, 6};
b = 0 g;

(* abbreviation for triple G sequence, top row, forehead, eye level *)
a = ##&[G, G, G];
t = {g, g, g, G, g, g, g, g};
f = {g, a, a, g};
e = {g, b, b, G, G, b, b, g};

(* slime *)
s =
  {
    t,
    f,
    e,
    e,
    {a, a, G, g},
    {g, a, b, a},
    f,
    t
  }/255;

(* jth column *)
c[n_, j_] := Join @@ Table[ImageData@ImageResize[Image[s], 4*2^j], 2^(n - j)]

(* final program *)
Image@Join[##, 2] & @@ Table[c[#, j], {j, #}] &
```

Comment: `b=0g`. To generate `s` it might be shorter to encode the pixel values as a base-3 number but I'd have to try to be sure. In the meantime, you can save bytes by not defining `b`, `g`, `f`, `e`, `t` until you need them, and `s` doesn't need a name at all and neither does `c`. For `2^(j-1)8` you can use `4*2^j`. Applying all of those, I end up at 225 bytes: http://pastebin.com/YnkUwvwV

Comment: @MartinEnder Much gratitude, these are all very good suggestions! (Note to self: avoid naming things if possible, otherwise do the assignment at (rather than before) the first occurrence.)

Comment: I don't have time to figure it out completely right now, but here is an idea to avoid the `Image`, `ImageResize`, `ImageData` stuff. This bit blows up an array by a factor of 2: `#&@@{##&@@{#,#}&//@x}` where `x` is the array. So if you do store the initial 8x8 grid in a variable `x`, and then do `x=#&@@{##&@@{#,#}&//@x}` after each use, you can generate the successive tiles quite easily.

Comment: Whoops, that's 4 bytes longer than it needs to be: `#&[##&[#,#]&//@x]`

Comment: Hm, I'm not getting this to work yet, but you can save some more by a) using `##~Join~2` and b) `f={g,a=##&[G,G,G],a,g}` and then replace every further occurrence of `G,G,G` with `a` as well.

Comment: @MartinEnder a) While `Join[##,2]&` and `##~Join~2&` are the same, `Image@Join[##,2]&` and `Image@##~Join~2&` aren't, as `@` takes precedence over `~Join~`. b) works fine, thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry about the `Join`, I had made some other local changes, where I didn't pass it straight to `Image@`.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.7: <del>424</del> <del>412</del> <del>405</del> <del>376</del> 357 Bytes

I'm a bit new to golfing.... here we go

```Python
from numpy import*
import PIL
def c(n,col):e=log2((col+8)/8)//1;r=2**e;t=2**(n-e-1);return tile(repeat(array([0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb/3**i%3for i in range(64)],dtype=int8).reshape([8,8])[:,(col-(8*r-8))//r],r),t)
n=input();i=PIL.Image.fromarray(column_stack([c(n,col) for col in range(2**(n+3)-8)]),mode='P');i.putpalette('t\xc4`n\xaaZ'+' '*762);i.show()
```

ungolfed and length tested..

```Python
from numpy import*
import PIL

def c(n,col): #creates array for a given column
    s = array([0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb/3**i%3for i in range(64)],dtype=int8).reshape([8,8]) #slime template (golfed inline)
    e=log2((col+8)/8)//1 #exponent for tiles and repititions
    r=2**e #number of repitions (scale factor)
    t=2**(n-e-1) #number of tiles (vertically)
    return tile(
            repeat(
             s[:,(col-(8*r-8))//r] #select appropriate column from template
              ,r) #repeat it r times
               ,t) #tile it t times

n = input()
arr = column_stack([c(n,col) for col in range(2**(n+3)-8)]) #create image array by stacking column function
i=PIL.Image.fromarray(arr,mode='P'); #colormap mode
i.putpalette('t\xc4`n\xaaZ'+' '*762); #set colormap
i.show()

s = r'''from numpy import*
import PIL
def c(n,col):e=log2((col+8)/8)//1;r=2**e;t=2**(n-e-1);return tile(repeat(array([0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb/3**i%3for i in range(64)],dtype=int8).reshape([8,8])[:,(col-(8*r-8))//r],r),t)
n=input();i=PIL.Image.fromarray(column_stack([c(n,col) for col in range(2**(n+3)-8)]),mode='P');i.putpalette('t\xc4`n\xaaZ'+' '*762);i.show()'''

print len(s)
```

edit1: removed `sys.argv[1]` in favor of `raw_input()` to save extra import statement

edit2: shortened PIL import: removed `from Image` added `PIL.`

edit3: Thanks @Sherlock9 for the hex encode of the slime template

edit4: didn't need function def and used `input()` instead of `raw_input()`

Comment: any suggestions are more than welcome :) especially to shrink the template array

Comment: Something like using `'0000100001111110111211100111111102211220022112200111111000001000'` (your array backwards) converted from base 3 to base 16 `0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb`. With that number, use code like this `[0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb//3**i%3 for i in range(64)]` to get your integers in the correct order.

Comment: Ah, in Python 2, `[0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb/3**i%3for i in range(64)]` may be better.

Comment: Thanks @Sherlock9 being new to golfing, could you explain how this (I assume) change of base code works?

Comment: First, I pretended that `00001000011111101112111001111111022112200221122001111110000‌​01000` is a base 3 integer (because there are 3 integers, `0`, `1`, and `2`). The shortest way to represent a number this that Python will still recognize as an number is in hexadecimal, base 16. So, in this case, I converted from base 3 to base 16 to get `0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb`.

Comment: The second part is to get your array back from that number `0x2df0777ca228b9c18447a6fb`. This is simple. For a simpler example, to get the `0`th digit from `01221100`, just divide by 3 `0` times, and then take the last digit (using mod 3) to get `0`. To take the 2nd digit, divide by 3 `2` times, then mod 3 to get `1`. The list comprehension just divides by 3 `64` times to get your full array back. If you have any more questions, we can discuss them in the [PPCG chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>378</s> <s>356</s> <s>346</s> 334 bytes

```
f=function(n){r=rep;k=r(0,4);m=r(1,6);L=c();for(i in 1:n)L=cbind(L,r(max(L,0)+2^(n-i):1,e=2^(i-1)));png(w=sum(w<-4*2^(1:n)),h=sum(h<-r(8,2^(n-1))));layout(L,w,h);for(i in 1:max(L)){par(mar=k);image(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,k,0,m,0,0,1,1,1,2,r(1,10),0,0,r(r(c(2,1,2,0),e=2),2),m,k,1,k),nr=8),col=c("#74C460","#6EAA5A",1),ax=F,an=F)};dev.off()}
```

Saves as a png file. Indented, with linefeeds:

```r
f=function(n){
    r=rep
    k=r(0,4)
    m=r(1,6)
    L=c()
    for(i in 1:n)L=cbind(L,r(max(L,0)+2^(n-i):1,e=2^(i-1)))
    png(w=sum(w<-4*2^(1:n)),h=sum(h<-r(8,2^(n-1))))
    layout(L,w,h)
    for(i in 1:max(L)){
        par(mar=k)
        image(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,k,0,m,0,
                       0,1,1,1,2,r(1,10),0,
                       0,r(r(c(2,1,2,0),e=2),2),
                       m,k,1,k),
                     nr=8),
              col=c("#74C460","#6EAA5A",1),ax=F,an=F)
    }
    dev.off()
}
```

N=2: [image: N=2]
N=3: [image: N=3]
N=4: [image: N=4]

Some explanations:

Here's the matrix that's being plotted (0 represent lightgreen, 1 darkgreen and 2 black; the matrix is tilted because columns are the y-axis and rows the x-axis):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    1    2    2    1    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    2    2    1    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    0    1    2    1    1    1    1    0
[6,]    0    1    1    1    2    2    1    0
[7,]    0    1    1    1    2    2    1    0
[8,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
```

Each call to `image` plot that matrix (with each integer corresponding to a color).
For N=4, here is L (the layout matrix, each unique number represents one single plot), w (the widths of the matrix columns) and h (the heights of the matrix rows):

```
> L
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    8   12   14   15
[2,]    7   12   14   15
[3,]    6   11   14   15
[4,]    5   11   14   15
[5,]    4   10   13   15
[6,]    3   10   13   15
[7,]    2    9   13   15
[8,]    1    9   13   15
> w
[1]  8 16 32 64
> h
[1] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 512 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;n->new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int N=n,o=0,p=1,t,q,u;N-->0;o+=8*p,p*=2)for(t=(int)Math.pow(2,N);t-->0;g.setColor(new Color(116,196,96)),g.fillRect(o,q=u*t,u,u),g.setColor(new Color(110,170,90)),g.fillRect(p+o,p+q,6*p,6*p),g.fillRect(o,4*p+q,p,p),g.fillRect(3*p+o,q,p,p),g.fillRect(7*p+o,5*p+q,p,p),g.fillRect(3*p+o,7*p+q,p,p),g.setColor(Color.BLACK),g.fillRect(p+o,2*p+q,2*p,2*p),g.fillRect(5*p+o,2*p+q,2*p,2*p),g.fillRect(4*p+o,5*p+q,p,p))u=8*p;}});show();}}
```

**Results for \$n=4,5,6\$:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;       // Required import for almost everything
n->                      // Method with integer parameter and Frame return-type
  new Frame(){           //  Create the Frame
   {                     //   In an inner code-block:
     add(new Panel(){    //    Add a Panel we can draw on:
       public void paint(Graphics g){
                         //     Overwrite its paint method:
         for(int N=n,    //      Create a copy of the (effectively final) input
                 o=0,    //      Offset integer, starting at 0
                 p=1,    //      Power integer, starting at 1
                 t,      //      Inner loop integer, starting uninitialized
                 q,u;    //      Temp integers, starting uninitialized
             N-->0       //      Loop `N` in the range (`n`, 0]:
             ;           //        After every iteration:
              o+=8*p,    //         Increase the offset by 8 times the power
              p*=2)      //         And go to the next power by doubling it
           for(t=(int)Math.pow(2,N);
                         //       Set `t` to 2^`N`
               t-->0     //       Inner loop `t` in the range (2^`N`, 0]:
               ;         //         After every iteration:
                g.setColor(new Color(116,196,96)),
                         //          Set the color to the lighter green
                g.fillRect(o,q=u*t,u,u),
                         //          Draw the background rectangle,
                         //          and set `q` to `u*t` to save bytes
                g.setColor(new Color(110,170,90)),
                         //          Change the color to the darker green
                g.fillRect(p+o,p+q,6*p,6*p),
                         //          Draw the inner rectangle
                g.fillRect(o,4*p+q,p,p),
                         //          Draw the left dot
                g.fillRect(3*p+o,q,p,p),
                         //          Draw the top dot
                g.fillRect(7*p+o,5*p+q,p,p),
                         //          Draw the right dot
                g.fillRect(3*p+o,7*p+q,p,p),
                         //          Draw the bottom dot
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK),
                         //          Change the color to black
                g.fillRect(p+o,2*p+q,2*p,2*p),
                         //          Draw the left eye
                g.fillRect(5*p+o,2*p+q,2*p,2*p),
                         //          Draw the right eye
                g.fillRect(4*p+o,5*p+q,p,p))
                         //          Draw the mouth
             u=8*p;}});  //        Set `u` to `8*p` to save bytes
     show();}}           //    And afterwards show the Frame
```